# Javascript Prompt Box Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, prompt

Something is wrong with this code but I can't figure out what it is. The page does not work properly or do what it's supposed to. I need a code that prompts for a password and that limits the attempts to 3. After the third attempt, it needs to have an alert box.

```
<script>
var attempts = 3;
var answer = prompt("Password: ");
while (attempts != 0) 
{
    if (answer == "Psycho")
    {
        document.write("These are pictures of my kitten and     her things.");
    }
    else
    {
        answer = prompt("Password: ");
        attempts--;
    }
}
if (attempts = 0) 
{
    alert("Incorrect Password");
}
</script>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to fix your code.
You could return once you're done the work.

```
<script>
var attempts = 3;
var answer = prompt("Password: ");
while (attempts != 0) 
{
    if (answer == "Psycho")
    {
        document.write("These are pictures of my kitten and     her things.");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        answer = prompt("Password: ");
        attempts--;
    }
}
if (attempts == 0) 
{
    alert("Incorrect Password");
}
</script>
```

Or, I would return early if you've failed

```
<script>
var attempts = 4;
var answer = prompt("Password: ");
while (attempts > 0 && answer != "Psycho") 
{
    answer = prompt("Password: ");
    attempts--;
}

if (attempts == 0) 
{
    alert("Incorrect Password");
}
else
{
    document.write("These are pictures of my kitten and     her things.");
}
</script>
```

Comment: @epascarello doh! fixed

Comment: return; should be break;

Comment: @Sheikah-coder wow that's a late reply hahaha. If you're commenting this it must have helped. Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues. You should check entry after the user enters in the prompt. Or the last entry will not be checked. Next issue is you are not exiting the loop. Another issue is the fact that `=` is assignment so inside the if you are assigning zero, not checking to see if it is zero.

```js
var attempts = 3;
while (attempts > 0) {
  var answer = prompt("Password: ");
  if (answer == "Psycho") {
    document.write("These are pictures of my kitten and her things.");
    break;
  }
  attempts--;
}
if (attempts == 0) {
  alert("Incorrect Password");
}
```